# Visual Studio C# {"ORA-00971: missing SET keyword"}

Tags: c#, oracle

I have a weird problem about an update query that i am working on. Take a look:

```
UPDATE DW.SLS_SLS_SCHEDE_SDS P1 
SET
P1.RECORD_INSERITO_AGGIORNATO = 'A',
P1.DATA_ELABORAZIONE = (SELECT DATA_INS_AGG_SDS 
                FROM DWH.SUMIGLOBAL P2 
                WHERE SUBSTR(P2.CODICE_PRODOTTO,1,6)= P1.COD_PRODOTTO 
                AND P2.DATA_INS_AGG_SDS>'20160400'
                AND (TO_NUMBER(TO_DATE(P1.DATA_ELABORAZIONE, 'YYYY/MM/DD') -  
TO_DATE(P2.DATA_INS_AGG_SDS,'YYYY/MM/DD')))>0
                AND (TO_NUMBER(TO_DATE(P1.DATA_ELABORAZIONE, 'YYYY/MM/DD') -  
TO_DATE(P2.DATA_INS_AGG_SDS,'YYYY/MM/DD')))<366)
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT * 
FROM DWH.SUMIGLOBAL P2
WHERE SUBSTR(P2.CODICE_PRODOTTO,1,6)= P1.COD_PRODOTTO 
AND P2.DATA_INS_AGG_SDS>'20160400'
AND (TO_NUMBER(TO_DATE(P1.DATA_ELABORAZIONE, 'YYYY/MM/DD') -  
TO_DATE(P2.DATA_INS_AGG_SDS,'YYYY/MM/DD')))>0
AND (TO_NUMBER(TO_DATE(P1.DATA_ELABORAZIONE, 'YYYY/MM/DD') -  
TO_DATE(P2.DATA_INS_AGG_SDS,'YYYY/MM/DD')))<366);
```

First of all i am using `Visual Studio 2015` also i use `toad for oracle 12.8` in which i have some records in the DB. When i execute the query inside the toad it works exactly as it should be.

Because i need to run the query from the VS, i have linked VS to the oracle and i execute the query so i get the following error

> {"ORA-00971: missing SET keyword"}.

This Error is from VS. I am sure that the problem has not to do with the code i wrote.

Code of C#

```
using (var dbContextTransaction = con.BeginTransaction())
        {
            const string selectCommandTextPianoAcq = "same query as before"
            var cmd = new OracleCommand
            {
                Connection = con,
                CommandText = selectCommandTextPianoAcq,
                CommandTimeout = 15,
                Transaction = dbContextTransaction
            };
            var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        }
```

Any idea why this happening ?

Comment: Looks like it's only trying to execute the first line; maybe the line breaks within your string are confusing it somehow?

Comment: Remove the table alias P1 from the first line: UPDATE DW.SLS_SLS_SCHEDE_SDS SET

Comment: @AlexPoole I found the problem it was a missing letter